# Ads messing up my article crawling

Tags: python, web-crawler, mechanize, pyquery

What do I need to do when trying to crawl an article, but an Ad of sorts keeps showing up? Specifically, the ones that would pop up in the middle of the screen, asking to log in/sign up, and you have to manually close it before reading.

Because of that, my crawl is unable to extract anything. Any advice on how to code in a "close ad before crawling" with pyquery?

Edit: Now working with Selenium to try and rid the pop-ups. Any advice would be much appreciated.

```
import mechanize
import time
import urllib2
import pdb
import lxml.html
import re
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

def open_url(url):    
    print 'open url:',url 

try:    
    br = mechanize.Browser()
    br.set_handle_equiv(True)
    br.set_handle_redirect(True)
    br.set_handle_referer(True)
    br.set_handle_robots(False)
    br.addheaders = [('user-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100423 Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.3')]
    response = br.open(url)
    html = response.get_data()
    return html
except:
    print u"!!!! url can not be open by mechanize either!!! \n"

def extract_text_pyquery(html):
    p = pq(html)
    article_whole = p.find(".entry-content")
    p_tag = article_whole('p')
    print len(p_tag)
    print p_tag
    for i in range (0, len(p_tag)):
        text = p_tag.eq(i).text()
        print text
    entire = p.find(".grid_12")
    author = entire.find('p')
    print len(author)
    print "By:", author.text()

    images = p.find('#main_photo')
    link = images('img')
    print len(link)
    for i in range(len(link)):
    url = pq(link[i])

    result =url.attr('src').find('smedia')
    if result>0:
        print url.attr('src')



if __name__ =='__main__':
    #print '----------------------------------------------------------------'

url_list = ['http://www.newsobserver.com/2014/10/17/4240490/obama-weighs-ebola-czar-texas.html?sp=/99/100/&ihp=1',


            ]
html= open_url(url_list[0])
# dissect_article(html)
extract_text_pyquery(html)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on continually crawling that specific site then you can check for elements with `id="continue_link` and pull the href from that.  Then load that page and scrape.

For example the url in your `url_list` it contained this element

```
<a href="http://www.bnd.com/2014/10/10/3447693_rude-high-school-football-players.html?rh=1" id="continue_link" class="wp_bold_link wp_color_link wp_goto_link">Skip this ad</a>
```

You can then navigate directly to that link without any sort of ad gateway.  I'm more familiar with BeautifulSoup than what you're using but it seems like you can do something like

```
p = pq(html)
if p.find("#continue_link):
    continue_link = p.find("#continue_link")
    html = open_url(continue_link('href'))
    extract_text_pyquery(html)
    return
<rest of code if there is no continue link>
```